# Iteration through matrix of sports players + probabilities

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, iteration

**The Objective**

I want to populate a grid which will hold a probability of one player getting a yellow card in a football ("soccer") match depending on 3 factors

player_rate: the average rate at which the player accumulates yellow cards (e.g. a value of 0.5 indicates that he would, on average, accumulate half a yellow card per game..or in practical terms, one every 2nd game)

team_names: the amount above or below the average rate, that a team causes opposition players to be booked (e.g.  a value of 0.10 indicates that you are are 10% more likely than average to be booked when playing them, whereas -0.10 indicates you are 10% less likely than average to be booked when playing them)

opponent_player_rates: the amount above or below the average rate, that players who play against this direct opponent accumulate yellow cards (e.g. a value of 0.05 indicates that you are are 5% more likely than average to be booked when playing against this specific opponent, than against the "average" opponent)

I seek to use this as the basis for the formula below, to calculate the likelihood of each player getting booked - after factoring in the 3 variables above

adjusted_likelihood = player_rate * (1 + team_rate + opponent_player_rate)

Using the code below I have approached this problem by constructing a dataframe which matches each of the 449 players against eachother (e.g. take a row for a "player" and read across. Each column gives a probability that this player will be booked when playing up against the player listed in the specific column)

**The Problem**

When I run this code, it calculates and populates the values only for the first row (i.e. index = 0, "player" = "Max Aarons"). But I want it to calculate the full matrix of values, so I can tell the likelihood of any player getting booked when up against any specific opponent player.

Note: Some NaN values on row 1 are expected (e.g. for column = "Bénie Adama Traore", as there are a subset of teams for which I have not yet created 'team_rates').

**The Code: to re-produce the output**

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

def calculate_adjusted_likelihood(player_rates, team_rates, opponent_player_rates):
    adjusted_likelihoods = []

    for player_rate, team_rate, opponent_player_rate in zip(player_rates, team_rates, opponent_player_rates):
        print(f"Debug: Player Rate ({player_name}): {player_rate}, Team Rate: {team_rate}, Opponent Player Rate: {opponent_player_rate}")
        adjusted_likelihood = player_rate * (1 + team_rate + opponent_player_rate)
        adjusted_likelihoods.append(adjusted_likelihood)
        print(f"Debug: Adjusted Likelihood ({player_name}): {adjusted_likelihood}")
    return adjusted_likelihoods

player_names = clubs_slim['player'].tolist()
player_rates = clubs_slim['Yellows per 90'].tolist()

# Load - AGAINST EACH PLAYER ROW - team names & average booking rates (for teams against them)
team_names = clubs_slim['squad'].tolist()
team_rates = clubs_slim['CrdY Against Avg relative'].tolist()

# construct the dataframe
df_likelihoods = pd.DataFrame(index=player_names, columns=player_names)

# Create list of opponent players % likelihood to cause a yellow
opponent_player_rates = clubs_slim['Yellow Threat Scaled'].tolist()

print("Length of player_names:", len(player_names))
print("Length of player_rates:", len(player_rates))
print("Length of team_names:", len(team_names))
print("Length of team_rates:", len(team_rates))
print("Length of opponent_player_rates:", len(opponent_player_rates))

# Call method to calculate adjusted likelihoods of being booked
adjusted_likelihoods = calculate_adjusted_likelihood(player_rates, team_rates, opponent_player_rates)

# Debugging print
print("Number of player names:", len(player_names))
print("Number of adjusted likelihoods:", len(adjusted_likelihoods))
print("Number of opponent_player_rates:", len(opponent_player_rates))
print("Adjusted Likelihoods:", adjusted_likelihoods)

# Populate DataFrame with adjusted likelihoods
for (player_name, opponent_name), likelihood in zip(product(player_names, repeat=2), adjusted_likelihoods):
    print(f"Player Name: {player_name}, Opponent Name: {opponent_name}")
    df_likelihoods.at[player_name, opponent_name] = likelihood

# Debugging print
print("Number of columns in df_likelihoods:", len(df_likelihoods.columns))

# Merge the columns into df_likelihoods
merged_df = clubs_slim[['player', 'squad', 'position', '90s', 'Yellows per 90', 'Yellow Threat']].merge(
    df_likelihoods.reset_index(),
    left_on='player',
    right_on='index'
)

merged_df.drop(['index'], axis=1, inplace=True)

# Debugging print
print("Number of columns in merged_df:", len(merged_df.columns))

merged_df.to_csv('booking_likelihood_dump.csv')

# Display the result
merged_df
```

**Images of dataframes**

**Dataframe:** merged_df

[image]

**Dataframe:** clubs_slim

[image]

**Dataframe:** PL_2223_misc_against

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was how I got it to work in the end, using enumerate and nested for loops

```
def calculate_adjusted_likelihood(player_rates, team_rates, opponent_player_rates):
    adjusted_likelihoods = []

    for i, player_rate in enumerate(player_rates):
        for j, team_rate in enumerate(team_rates):
            opponent_player_rate = opponent_player_rates[i % len(opponent_player_rates)]  # Use modulo for opponent player rate
            adjusted_likelihood = player_rate * (1 + team_rate + opponent_player_rate)
            adjusted_likelihoods.append(adjusted_likelihood)

    return adjusted_likelihoods
```

Comment: You are not using `j` anywhere. And with `itertools.cycle()` and `zip()` you may get rid of `i` and `%` too and be able to use just one expression: `return [player_rate * (1 + team_rate + opponent_player_rate) for player_rate, opponent_player_rate in zip(player_rates, cycle(opponent_player_rates)) for team_rate in team_rates]`. Of course that should be formatted in a more readable way than possible in a comment here.